# Can't get excel VBA code to execute from another program

Tags: excel, vba, solidworks

I'm trying to run a macro from Solidworks which involves opening a previously created excel sheet and running a few commands for formatting/organisation. I recorded the necessary macro and tried to past it into the VBA editor through Solidworks and I can't figure out how to get the code to run properly. When running the macro, Excel runs and opens the relevant sheet but none of the commands from `Range("A1:C3"). Select` onwards works, it's just the unaltered data. Is there something I'm missing?

I'm choosing to run the command from SolidWorks for convenience/self-containment and it's much easier to import macros on different machines than excel. Thanks!

```
Sub RunExcelMacro()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\sheet.csv")

Dim objExcel As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Open "F:\sheet.csv"
On Error Resume Next
Excel.Application.Run "F:\sheet.csv"

Range("A1:C3").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
etc...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is based in Excel as being the host application. Top level commands like `Range` and `Selection` run against the `Application` object, which if you've copied this code to SolidWorks then the `Application` object is no longer `Excel` it's `SolidWorks`.

You can use Excel application commands like this:

```
With objExcel

    .Run "F:\sheet.csv"
    
    .Range("A1:C3").Select
    .Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With .Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
End With
etc...
```

Notice I've added leading dots to call those commands against the application in the with block.

**2nd problem**

You are trying to run a macro in a `CSV` file. CSV files can't contain macros. You also didn't cite a macro name. If you want to run a macro in a foreign workbook you must first open a valid macro enabled workbook and then call the macro by name.

It would look like this:

```
objExcel.Run "F:\sheet.xlsm!MyMacroName"
```

So that `.xlsm` file must exist and it must contain `MyMacroName` for that to work.

Comment: ... and OP is mixing early- and late-binding, plus creating two instances of Excel :-). I'm sure you'd add those to your answer eventually anyway. There's quite a few issues.

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty much learning as I go to deal with this very specific problem. Is there not a way where I can just run the commands within this macro rather than making one to reference it? As in, "here's a workbook, now do this with it". I'm trying to make this easy to send over for other people to use.

Comment: Alright, so I included the extra code you suggested which just selects the given cells, which is a start? I think I can mess around with it to get it to do what I'm looking for. Thank you

Comment: There is always more than one way to do things. How you should approach it is a question of design, architecture, and engineering. If I've answered your question please mark this question as solved with the green checkmark to the left. This will close out the question so people don't come back trying to solve your problem.